# Build a struct with a struct inside

Tags: c, struct

```
typedef struct Course {
char *CourseID;
char *CourseName;
struct Course* next;
} COURSE; 

typedef struct Student{
int ID;
struct Student* next
}STUDENT;
```

I want to build a list of courses and then a list of students with the following
each student has an ID and some courses from the courses list and a grade of each course.
but how can I make that declaration inside the STUDENT struct? I cant understand that

For example
Student: 3049583222
Course: Biology (from course list)
grade: 30

and so on, every student could have all courses from the list.

Comment: That's a start. How much further along did you get?

Comment: Well, I don't have the understanding how do I create a struct of students with each student having a course I choose and a grade, I mean syntax wise how could I write that inside the students struct?

Comment: You want a linked list of a courses for every student which holds the grade and a pointer to a more detailed course description? I dont completly understand the question?

Comment: Okey sorry for the missundetstanding, I want a list of courses with unlimited amount of courses, then I want a list of students with unlimited amount fo students, every student has an ID and some or all courses from the course list, also for each course that a student has, he has a grade too

Comment: Translating literally: "having a course" -> `struct Course* course`, and "a grade" -> `int grade`. These are properties on `Student`.

Comment: What do I do if a student has more then one course? and I need him to have lets say two courses with two grades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea:

- Linked List of Students.
- Every student has a linked list of its courses with the grade.
- The linked list elements have a pointer to the detailed course description.

```
// Description of a course
typedef struct Course {
char *CourseID;
char *CourseName;
} COURSE; 


// Struct to hold the students grade, as a linked list to generate a list of all courses the student has.
typedef struct coursesTaken {
    int grade;
    COURSE* courseDescription;
    struct coursesTaken* nextCourse;
} COURSES_TAKEN;


// The student with ID and pointer to his first course.
typedef struct Student{
int ID;
COURSES_TAKEN* firstCourse;
struct Student* next;
}STUDENT;
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple ways to do that, below shown are two approaches.

You can pick one and build on it.

```
typedef struct Course {
    char *CourseID;
    char *CourseName;
    struct Course* next;
} COURSE; 

typedef struct Student{
    int ID;
}STUDENT;

//approach 1
#define NIDS 10
#define NCOURSES 20

typedef struct Student_Course_1{
    STUDENT STU_ID[NIDS];           /* to store list of student ids */
    COURSE STU_Courses[NCOURSES];   /* to store list of courses    */
}COURSES_OF_STUDENT_1;

//approach 2

typedef struct Student_Course_2{
    STUDENT STU_ID;
    COURSE STU_Courses;
}COURSES_OF_STUDENT_2;


int main()
{
    COURSES_OF_STUDENT_1 cs1;       /* this has list of students and courses inside it */
    COURSES_OF_STUDENT_2 cs2[NIDS]; /* you can use NIDS list of students and courses info with this */
    
    return 0;
}
```